# reuse of subqueries with different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which I looks schematically like this

```
WITH sub_base AS (
SELECT type,
CASE WHEN a < 10 THEN 'GOOD'
     WHEN a BETWEEN 10 AND 100 THEN 'OK'
     ELSE 'BAD'
END AS a_q,
...
CASE WHEN z < 5 THEN 'GOOD'
     WHEN z BETWEEN 5 AND 50 THEN 'OK'
     ELSE 'BAD'
END AS z_q
FROM tbl
),

SELECT sub_one AS (
SELECT 'one' AS type,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) a_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) a_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) a_bad,
...
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) z_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) z_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) z_bad,
FROM sub_base
WHERE type = 'one'
),

SELECT sub_two AS (
SELECT 'two' AS type,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) a_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) a_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) a_bad,
...
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) z_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) z_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) z_bad,
FROM sub_base
WHERE type = 'two'
),

SELECT sub_all AS (
SELECT 'all' AS type,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) a_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) a_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) a_bad,
...
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) z_good,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) z_ok,
COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) z_bad,
FROM sub_base
)

SELECT * FROM sub_one
UNION
SELECT * FROM sub_two
UNION
SELECT * FROM sub_all
```

I want to reuse the subqueries in `sub_one, sub_two, sub_all` because they are almost identical with the exception of `type` in SELECT and the WHERE condition.

How can I avoid copy-pasting these subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT type,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) as a_good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) as a_ok,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) as a_bad,
       ...
       COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) as z_good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) as z_ok,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) as z_bad,
FROM sub_base
WHERE type IN ('one', 'two', 'three')  -- may not be needed
GROUP BY type;
```

In Postgres, I would further simplify this.  You could use `FILTER` or summing binary values:

```
SELECT type,
       SUM( (a_q = 'GOOD')::int ) as a_good,
       SUM( (a_q = 'OK')::int ) as a_ok,
       SUM( (a_q = 'BAD')::int ) as a_bad,
       ...
       SUM( (z_q = 'GOOD')::int ) as z_good,
       SUM( (z_q = 'OK')::int ) as z_ok,
       SUM( (z_q = 'BAD')::int ) as z_bad,
FROM sub_base
WHERE type IN ('one', 'two', 'three')  -- may not be needed
GROUP BY type;
```

I would also dispense with the CTE and just put the logic in the outer query directly, but that is more a matter of style.

EDIT:

You can use another CTE:

```
WITH . . . ,
     t as (
      SELECT type,
             SUM( (a_q = 'GOOD')::int ) as a_good,
             SUM( (a_q = 'OK')::int ) as a_ok,
             SUM( (a_q = 'BAD')::int ) as a_bad,
             ...
             SUM( (z_q = 'GOOD')::int ) as z_good,
             SUM( (z_q = 'OK')::int ) as z_ok,
             SUM( (z_q = 'BAD')::int ) as z_bad,
      FROM sub_base
      WHERE type IN ('one', 'two', 'three')  -- may not be needed
      GROUP BY type
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(a_good), SUM(a_ok), SUM(a_bad), . . .
FROM t;
```

Comment: I like group by approach. The only problem is that it's not 'three' but 'all', meaning 'one' or 'two'. In some DB I can use WITH ROLLUP but I'm working with Redshift which doesn't support it

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a second CTE?

```
WITH sub_base AS (
    ...
),
second_cte AS (
    SELECT  
        type,  
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) a_good,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) a_ok,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) a_bad,
        ...
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) z_good,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) z_ok,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) z_bad
    FROM sub_base
)
SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'one'

UNION

SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'two'

UNION

SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'all'
```

---

You don't even need two CTE's in your case, because you don't reuse the first one. So you can put it into a subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT    
        type,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) a_good,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'OK' THEN 1) a_ok,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) a_bad,
        ...
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'GOOD' THEN 1) z_good,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'OK' THEN 1) z_ok,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN z_q = 'BAD' THEN 1) z_bad
    FROM (
        SELECT
            <your sub_base query here>
    ) s
)
SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'one'

UNION

SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'two'

UNION

SELECT
    *
FROM second_cte
WHERE type = 'all'
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it might work, I just need to figure out what to do with type, which doesn't exist in cte, or in second_cte. I can add it but then I need to select * except type.

Comment: You're right. Fixed it, added the type into the second cte and the superiour query